# I am using stringify to post an object to php in php even integers are string how can i fix this?

Tags: php, jquery, json, stringify

I am using stringify to post an object to php,

In php i use `json_decode($object,true)` to get the object back into a object for and not a string.

However the values stay strings even for integers.

My question is there a way to decode it to it's original form ?

ints to ints.
string to stings ..

Thanks

Comment: Well, in php strings and ints ae interchangeable as long as it's made of numbers. There shouldnt be much reason for concern.

Comment: that will work if i go over all the object items . i am asking to see if there is something more general

Comment: MightyPorl the object goes to api call that checks for string/integers that's why i am asking

Comment: You're probably mixing up numeric strings with integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you're getting at:

```
php > var_dump(json_decode(42)); // decoding a PHP int
int(42)
php > var_dump(json_decode('42')); // decoding a PHP string
int(42)
php > var_dump(json_decode('"42"')); // decoding a json string, containing a number
int(42)
php > var_dump(json_decode('foo')); // decoding invalid json
NULL
php > var_dump(json_decode('"foo"')); // decoding a valid string
string(3) "foo"
php > var_dump(json_decode('{"42":"foo"}')); // json object
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["42"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
}
```

Comment: For some odd reason for me var_dump return sting()... maybe i am doing something wrong.

Comment: marc Would it matter that the value comes from field ?

Comment: @NetaMeta Yes -- that is a **numeric string**, which is different than a integer *type*

Comment: field? as in an html form? then yes. EVERYTHING that comes from an html form is internally a string, even if it's just a "number".

Comment: `is_numeric` will help you identify numeric strings. To identify strings, you would need something like this: `function canBeString($value) {
    if (is_object($value) and method_exists($value, '__toString')) return true;
    if (is_null($value)) return true;
    return is_scalar($value);
}` -- you can just treat a number like a string, so there's no need to check for an actual string type, which is what `is_string` does.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your JSON is wrong, and has the ints as strings in that.

```
php> $o = json_decode('{"test": 42}')
=> stdClass Object
(
    [test] => 42
)
php> is_int($o->test)
=> 1
```

If they're properly ints in the JSON, they're ints coming out of json_decode.

Answer (score 0):

PHP *will* decode an integer as an integer if the value doesn't have quotes around it in the json string.

See here for an example: http://3v4l.org/ue67M

So you need to ensure that in the json you have `"myint": 1` and not `"myint": "1"`.

Which means the real issue here is the how you are creating the json in the first place.